# Possible to use one flow to route sms messages

Tags: twilio

I'm new to studio

I want to forward an sms message to each of my agents main numbers.  Is it possible to use one flow and have a logic map route messages based on the number the message was sent to, or should I set up different flow for each phone number?    ( thinking about keeping my flow diagram somewhat clean.)   If this is possible how can I setup this login in Flow

Is there a great resource to learn more about some powerful examples and video tutorials on how to work with FLOW?